# Autoload service in Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

A lot of my controllers use the [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http) service like this:

```
app.controller("MyController", function($scope, $http){
  ...
});
```

Is it possible to autoload services so I don't have to keep typing `$http` in the function params?

Comment: The only way I can think to do this is to create a global JS variable that is initialized in `app.run` or a similar block. [See here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) for details on `app.run` (search for run block).

Comment: even if you use global Js variable, you have to inject this service everywhere. sorry but I don't think so.

Comment: I can kind of see a way by creating a decorator for the `$controller` service and overloading the controller context for each instance, but that would be really hacky and a testing nightmare. I'm afraid you're going to have to just suck it up and write out the extra 5 or 6 characters.

Comment: PS. What IDE are you using?  You can create "live templates" in most IDEs that would allow you to define a quick boilerplate for all of your controllers that would auto-generate all of your controller dependencies.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses!. At least I now know its not possible. @tennisgent Im using Netbeans but even then id prefer it does it in code rather than the ide do it for you. Thanks again.